# ImportError when moving a file into a subfolder

Tags: python, import, runtime-error

Say I have the following file structure..

```
src/
main.py
requirements.txt
README.md
```

Where `requirements.txt` contains..

```
slackclient==1.0.7
```

And `main.py` contains..

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import os

def main():
    sc = SlackClient(os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It executes correctly, but when I move `main.py` into `src/`, like..

```
src/
src/main.py
requirements.txt
README.md
```

I receive an `ImportError: cannot import name SlackClient` error.

**Why is this?**

Comment: Can you please share some more code from main.py?

Comment: Sure, updated :)